# XCode 7.3.1 Archive Error: "Verify that your build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundle resources"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I'm having the problem that, whenever I want to archive my iPad App for AdHoc Apps I m getting "Verify that your build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundle resources".

So it also complains that the archive process can't find anything to sign with.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `project navigator` select your project and then goes to `build phases` under the target and check that is there your every classes, storyboards, assets or frameworks are there in `compile sources,copy bundle resource, link binaries with library,`.

Check below screenshot,

[image]

your `compile sources` should have your all classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Xcode 12`, make sure `arm64` architecture is included:

In Xcode 12, make sure arm64 architecture is included:

In your Target -> Build Settings search for:

1. `VALID_ARCHS` and make sure `arm64` is included.
2. search for `Excluded Architectures` and make sure `arm64` is NOT mentioned there.